# binance api get_historical_klines returns wrong value

Tags: python, csv, helper, binance-api-client

I have the following code:

```
def gethistory(symbol, LT):

    df = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(symbol, '1d',limit=1000,start_str = 
                                                         str(delta), end_str = None)) 
                                              //delta = date.today() - timedelta(days = LT)
    closes = pd.DataFrame(df[4])
    closes.columns = ['Close']
    
    closes['ST'] = closes.Close.rolling(ST-1).sum() //ST = 7
    closes['LT'] = closes.Close.rolling(LT-1).sum()
    
    return closes

historicals = gethistory('BTCUSDT', LT)  // LT = 25
```

which returns:

```
            Close         ST  LT
0  43893.22000000        NaN NaN
1  42454.70000000        NaN NaN
2  39148.36000000        NaN NaN
3  39398.19000000        NaN NaN
4  38420.80000000        NaN NaN
5  38061.30000000  241376.57 NaN
```

Why does it return only 6 rows?  The limit is 1000 and I ask for 25 days so it should return 25 rows.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an example**

`frame = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(symbol, '1d', '365 days ago UTC'))`

Hag sameah!